# Maven unpack only some dependencies

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin, ant-contrib, maven-antrun-plugin

Having the a maven project with a lot of dependencies I want unpack only some of them. Can I somehow group my dependencies so I can unpack only those by referencing the group?

I have found sort of a way but it seems a hassle:

Using dependencyfilesets I would be able to iterate over all maven's classpath maven.project.dependencies using a fileset. And each project would contain a properties file which could indicate that the project should be unpacked or not.
I'm afraid that overwriting maven properties for each iteration over the classpath could be faulty.

I'm hoping for suggestions on what would be the best maven way, I also found maven ant tasks that seems able to do the job but I am not considering using anything else than antrun/ant-contrib.

Small history: This is a migration from a ant project that uses something similar to a pom file but groupes dependencies and has different behavior per group. The dependencies contain java and javascript. I am interested in the javascript sources.

Comment: Why do you need to unpack dependencies?

Comment: Because I need the source files for further steps

Comment: Which kind of steps? You have dependencies and you use them on the classpath or package the jar's into a zip file etc. but the source?

Comment: I need the JavaScript files because I will run shrinksafe on them.

Comment: Hm...that sounds you should go a different way by using npm etc. instead of Maven for such things...If the java script files are packaged into jar's that seemed to be wrong...

Comment: I can't use npm, as I said, it's a migration from legacy ant and it uses rhino. Also, the dependencies do not contain only the javascript, they contain also java code.